# height: webkit-fill-available is not constant

Tags: css, ios, capacitor

I am building a capacitor app that works well on android but on ios using 100vh for the page causes some scrolling issues. I found the solution on [css tricks](https://css-tricks.com/css-fix-for-100vh-in-mobile-webkit/) using `height: -webkit-fill-available;` but using that only works well the first time user opens the app.
When you kill then reopen the app, then it only takes about `97vh`.

**Update:**
I found a better solution using javascript [here](https://gist.github.com/getify/150ea5a3b30b8822dee7798883d120b9)